# Can I pass a variable that captures string values (which is basically a url with token) in the @DefaultUrl in Serenity-JAVA Test Automation Framework

Tags: serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I am using Serenity Java based test automation framework with the below listed dependencies.

```
    <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <java.source.version>${java.version}</java.source.version>
    <java.target.version>${java.version}</java.target.version>
    <surefire.forkNumber>8</surefire.forkNumber>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <serenity.version>2.0.69</serenity.version> <!-- https://bintray.com/serenity/maven/serenity-core/ -->
    <serenity.maven.version>2.0.67</serenity.maven.version>
    <serenity.cucumber.version>1.9.45</serenity.cucumber.version> <!-- https://bintray.com/serenity/maven/serenity-cucumber/ -->
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.version>3.5.3</maven.version>
    <parallel.tests>4</parallel.tests>
    <browserstack.local.version>1.0.3</browserstack.local.version>
    <maven.failsafe-plugin.version>3.0.0-M3</maven.failsafe-plugin.version>
    <maven.surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M3</maven.surefire-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler-plugin.version>3.8.0</maven.compiler-plugin.version>
    <cucumber-jvm-parallel.version>5.0.0</cucumber-jvm-parallel.version>
```

I would like to pass a URL on the fly to @DefaultUrl which is not straightforward. By saying that I mean there are some restrictions to over come the crawlers and hence there is a token generated at a certain interval.So it is the url followed by a token kinda thing that would give access to application.

So token keeps changing. I created a class with a method that captures the url with the token calling the method every time. The actual issue is there. I want to pass the value from this method which is a url. I am looking for an option to make this a default url.

When I try with an environment without token it works fine and tests seems to run according to serenity.properties file. But as soon as I try to run my tests on the environment which is token based url I see that serenity.properties being ignored.
I tried something like this:

Given stepdef has

```
homePage.onDocsDashboard();
```

HomePage Dashboard

```
@DefaultUrl("Here goes the link to Main Page accessible by public but not the actual application page on INT environment ")
```

```html
public class HomePage extends PageObject {
private final AuthorisedUser authorisedUser = new AuthorisedUser();
Private String IntUrl = authorisedUser.IntEnvUrl;
public void onDocsDashboard() {
        open();
        getDriver().manage().window().maximize();
        getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        getDriver().navigate().to(IntUrl);
        getDriver().getCurrentUrl();
    }
}https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```